# Compare 2-dimensional array with 1-dimensional array and remove matching entries (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a two-dimensional array like this:

```
all = [
    [bla, bla, ID1, bla, bla],
    [bla, bla, ID2, bla, bla],
    [bla, bla, ID3, bla, bla],
    [bla, bla, ID4, bla, bla],
    [bla, bla, ID5, bla, bla],
    [bla, bla, ID6, bla, bla]
]
```

Next, I have a one-dimensional array like this:

```
selected = [ID1, ID2, ID6]
```

I need to remove all entries from my array `all` where the ID value does not match any ID in my array `selected`. From the example above I would then get a new array like this:

```
reduced = [
    [bla, bla, ID1, bla, bla],
    [bla, bla, ID2, bla, bla],
    [bla, bla, ID6, bla, bla]
]
```

How can I get an array like this?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Worth taking a look at [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) if you ware going to be doing a lot of this. But as you say *selected* there might be a better approach to what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can one line this using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var reduced = all.filter(function (a) {return selected.indexOf(a[2]) !== -1;});
```

It simply means, if `all[i][2]` (the value from the ID col) is in the selected array, keep this entry. It builds a new *Array* so `all` and `selected` won't be affected by this process.

It may be slightly faster to use a loop to do the same test, as it will mean less function overhead

```
var reduced = [], i = 0;
for (; i<all.length; ++i)
    if (selected.indexOf(all[i][2]) !== -1)
        reduced[reduced.length] = all[i];
```

Comment: Thanks! Also for your explanation.